# type mismatch error , when return an array in a function

Tags: function, excel, vba

I have a stupid question, I always got the error type mismatch when I created a function which return a array. here are two simple example :
if I don't declare the type when declaration: It will be compiled, but got the error after the function result

```
Function aa(c As Integer)
Dim arr(10)
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Double
For i = 0 To 10
    k = i ^ 2 / c + 1
    arr(i) = CStr(k)
    Debug.Print k
Next i
aa = arr
End Function
```

if i declare the type: it can't be compiled and will get the error directly

```
Function aa(c As Integer) as string()

Dim arr(10) as string 
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Double
For i = 0 To 10
    k = i ^ 2 / c + 1
    arr(i) = CStr(k)
    Debug.Print k
Next i
aa = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second version will work if you call it this way, using the same type:

```
Sub Testaa()
    Dim result() As String

    result = aa(4)      
End Sub
```

Your first version will return a `Variant` - any function (or variable) that isn't given a specific type will default to `Variant`. So you need to store the return result in a Variant as well:

```
Sub Testaa()
    Dim result As Variant

    result = aa(4)
End Sub
```

---

It is preferable to use explicit types wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I want use the function directly, how can I modify it in order to avoid the type mismatch error?

Comment: What do you mean by calling the function directly? If you want to use the function in worksheet-cells then it requires more work. See [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx) about returning an array from a UDF.